# targeting different android devices

Tags: android, layout, device, target

I know you can set specific layouts for a device like this:

```
if(android.os.Build.MODEL.equals("Galaxy S II")){

        setContentView(R.layout.resultsGS2);
    }
    else if(android.os.Build.MODEL.equals("Nexus 7")){
        setContentView(R.layout.resultsN7);
    }
    else{

        setContentView(R.layout.results);
    }
```

But what I want is to make a layout for all devices that have similar screen size/dimensions. I have been looking at this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html and I tried renaming the layout folder many different things and whenever I try to edit an xml file in the new layout folder I made and I change the device preview it keeps changing back to the default layout. I am using android studio, and basing the need to make a new layout off of the device previews that it shows. Is there is an easier way to do this besides making a layout for each specific device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by having different layout folders and calling them `layout- + screen size name` and then edit the layouts inside these folders to match the screen size you are targeting.

So for example if you wanted to target something such as the galaxy nexus (320dpi) you would create a folder called `layout-xhdpi` and all the device specific layouts will be placed in here. And then if you were to run this in an emulator or a physical device you would see the layout that you made specifically for that screen size.